# Joining Fields according to some condition in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have  Data Like this

```
  TagNo  FromBay   FromPanel ToBay  ToPanel  FromDevice  FromTerminal FromRef
   1000    +A        =D       +E       +F      +X1          1             D1
   1001    +A        =D       +E       +F      +X1          1             D2
   1001    +A        =D       +E       +F      +X1          2             D3
   1002    +A        =D       +E       +F      +X1          2             D4
   1000    +A        =D       +E       +F      +X5          2             D5
```

I want to have this

```
  TagNo        FromBay   FromPanel ToBay  ToPanel  FromDevice  FromTerminal   FromRef
   1000,1001    +A        =D       +E       +F      +X1          1            D1,D2
   1001,1002    +A        =D       +E       +F      +X1          2            D3,D4
```

it means that if FromBay   FromPanel ToBay  ToPanel  FromDevice have the  same value, return the concatenated TagNo and FromRef of those reocrds

how can i do that in TSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the concatenation it's only for pair of rows you can do this:

```
select t1.TagNo + ',' + t2.TagNo as TagNo,
t1.FromBay,t1.FromPanel,t1.ToBay,t1.ToPanel,t1.FromDevice,t1.FromTerminal,
t1.FromRef + ',' + t2.FromRef
from t t1
inner join t t2
on (t1.FromBay=t2.FromBay and t1.FromPanel=t2.FromPanel 
and t1.ToBay=t2.ToBay and t1.ToPanel=t2.ToPanel 
and t1.FromDevice=t2.FromDevice and t1.FromTerminal=t2.FromTerminal
and t1.TagNo<t2.TagNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get your output using ***XML PATH***, have created a sample in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c463/2), have not used all the columns that you need, however you should be able to get what you want with the sample:

```
SELECT FromBay,FromTerminal, 
FromRef = STUFF((SELECT ',' + FromRef FROM GroupTbl i
                          WHERE
                          i.FromBay = o.FromBay AND
                          i.FromTerminal = o.FromTerminal
                            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),
TagNo = STUFF((SELECT ',' + TagNo FROM GroupTbl i
                          WHERE
                          i.FromBay = o.FromBay AND
                          i.FromTerminal = o.FromTerminal
                            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM GroupTbl o
GROUP BY FromBay,FromTerminal
```